# Get foreign key, and corresponding field values into model

Tags: django

I have a model which I am using a foreign key from another model.
I need to also set another column to a corresponding field of that foreign key but am unsure how to do so correctly.

I am wanting to do it this way to work with a function I have setup in ModelC that should match the po_number from ModelA, then match the sku_number on Model B in the save() function.

```
Class ModelA(models.Model):
    po_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)


Class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    Value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sku_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def calc_received(self):
        sum_value = ModelC.objects.filter(
            sku_number=self.sku_number
          ).aggregate(
              value_sum=Sum(F('value'))
          )
          value_received = sum_value['value_sum']

          return value_received


Class ModelC(models.Model):
    po_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sku_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        obj = ModelB.objects.get(
            po_number=self.po_number,
            sku_number = self.sku_number
          )

        obj.value_received = obj.calc_received()
        obj.save()
```

How can I get the db structure to be something similiar to:

```
id     ModelA_id     ValueFromA
_______________________________
```

Currently I am trying

```
def _get_valuefromB(self):
    return self.ModelB.Value
value = property(_get_valuefromB
```

Comment: Is there a reason why can't just use `model_instance_A.ModelB.Value`?

Comment: Also, it's against [Django's coding style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style) to name your fields with uppercase letters. `Value = ...` should be `value = ...`, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question right you need something like this

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    model_b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    @property
    def value_b(self):
        return self.model_b.Value
```

Comment: The issue i'm having is it will not reflect in a migration to add that column to postgres

Comment: So you want a column in ModelA which always be the same as Value in ModelB?

Comment: Yes, if it is possible

Comment: Why do you want it? All the relation databases invented to get rid of redundancy of data, and you want to keep the same data in to places. Maybe you'd better get rid of ModelB and put all the fields in on table.

Comment: I've updated my post. Basically I have a function and I want it to match a value from modelA, then match a value from ModelB. However ModelB stores the FK from modelA. So my thought was that I could just add that value in modelB, instead of doing matching on each model.